# Issue with video uploader

Tags: php, github

So I've tried making my own youtube clone with https://github.com/the-real-sumsome/subrocks-2012 , and I've set up everything, the only thing that doesn't work is uploading, whenever I do, I get

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(../dynamic/temp/zGuPkekXR-S.mp4): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>/var/www/html/d/upload.php</b> on line <b>50</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpWeY4fd' to '../dynamic/temp/zGuPkekXR-S.mp4' in <b>/var/www/html/d/upload.php</b> on line <b>50</b><br />
Failed to move temp file to dynamic folder. Pottential IO/permission problem.0
```

Image: [image]
The VPS I'm using is from Oracle.

I tried running

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /tmp
```

and it didn't work, so I tried to check the code for something, I couldn't understand the issue.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: It looks like the problem isn't with the permissions of `/tmp`, but the permissions of `../dynamic/temp`. Try repairing the permissions of this directory by `chown`-ing it to the same user that runs your webserver, then use `chmod` to set the permissions to something like `664` to allow user/group read/write access. In general, it's a bad idea to blindly allow global execute permission on a directory, especially if it is open to user uploads.

Comment: @garrettmills Same error.

Comment: @NicoHaase the code is: 
    if(move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['video_file']['tmp_name'], 
        "../dynamic/temp/" . $video_properties->video_rid . $video_validation->video_file_type
    )) {
        $video_properties->video_filename = "../dynamic/temp/" . $video_properties->video_rid . $video_validation->video_file_type;
    } else {

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, along with your attempts to resolve the problem